# TSQL: JOIN, for sure it is possible -- but don't know how

Tags: t-sql, join

TABLE: Services:

```
ServiceID ServiceName  
1         Cleaning  
2         Painting  
3         Driving  
4         Cooking
```

TABLE: ServiceMembers:

```
ServiceMemberID  MemberID ServiceID  
1                10       3
```

Query:

```
SELECT s.ServiceName, sm.MemberID
FROM Services s
JOIN ServiceMembers sm ON s.ServiceID = sm.ServiceID
WHERE sm.MemberID = 10
```

Returns:

```
Driving    10
```

Question:
How to JOIN tables, so I can get following in TSQL:

```
Cleaning      NULL
Painting      NULL
Driving       10
Cooking       NULL
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do it:

```
SELECT s.ServiceName, sm.MemberID
FROM Services s
  LEFT JOIN ServiceMembers sm ON s.ServiceID = sm.ServiceID AND sm.MemberID = 10
```

Comment: This did it. I was doing LEFT JOIN only, but the difference is that I was having the sm.MemberID in the WHERE clause. Any thoughts how this is different. SELECT s.ServiceName, sm.MemberID
FROM Services s
  LEFT JOIN ServiceMembers sm ON s.ServiceID = sm.ServiceID WHERE sm.MemberID = 10

Comment: The WHERE clause effectively turns the outer join into an inner join. Think about what happens: first the outer join will return rows that have a NULL value in the sm.MemberID column. Then the WERE clause removes all rows from the result set where the MemberID equals 10 - which removes those that are NULL due to the outer join.